# transpose long to wide within groups with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I cant quite work this one out.
How do I go from:

```
Visit Test
1     A
1     B
2     A
2     C
3     B
```

To:

```
Visit A     B     C
1     TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
2     TRUE  FALSE TRUE
3     FALSE TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can do

```
dd %>% mutate(Value=TRUE) %>% 
  spread(Test, Value, fill=FALSE)

#   Visit     A     B     C
# 1     1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2     2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3     3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

tested with

```
dd<-read.table(text="Visit Test
       1     A
       1     B
       2     A
       2     C
       3     B", header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `reshape2::dcast` with `fun.aggregate` to check if `length` is greater than `0`.

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df,Visit~Test, fun.aggregate = function(x)length(x)>0, value.var = "Test")

#   Visit     A     B     C
# 1     1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2     2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3     3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Data:**

```
df<-read.table(text="Visit Test
1     A
1     B
2     A
2     C
3     B", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```